# Who invented train/validation/Test method and when?

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, inference, unbiased-estimator

I can't seem to find here or in other places the earliest source for this method.
it seems the holdout method was separately proposed by Highleyman in 1962,
and cross validation was separately proposed by Stone in 1974,
but the mixture of those two method resulting the train/validation/test is yet to be credited to one person.
is this the truth? 
earliest source here is the Bishop book in 1995, but I don't think he is the one responsible for proposing this in literature .